# Take one value, put it to anothers tables value and calculate sum

Tags: php, mysql

This is the situation. I have two tables, like this:

```
TABLE (haveToBuy):
+--------------------+
| product | quantity |
+--------------------+
| cake    | 3        |
| egg     | 2        |
| milk    | 5        |
+--------------------+

TABLE (alreadyBough):
+--------------------+
| product | quantity |
+--------------------+
| cake    | 1        |
| egg     | 0        |
| milk    | 5        |
+--------------------+
```

Now I want to update the quantity value of TABLE (alreadyBough), so it would look something like this:

```
TABLE (haveToBuy):
+--------------------+
| product | quantity |
+--------------------+
| cake    | 3        |
| egg     | 0        |
| milk    | 5        |
+--------------------+

TABLE (alreadyBought):
+--------------------+
| product | quantity |
+--------------------+
| cake    | 1        |
| egg     | 2        |
| milk    | 5        |
+--------------------+
```

(2 eggs moved from TABLE (haveToBuy) to TABLE (alreadyBought)). What would the query look like? How can I fix this query:

```
$query = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO alreadyBought (quantity) SELECT quantity  FROM haveToBuy WHERE product='$productID' ");
```

Comment: i think you need to use `update` query because in `alreadyBought` table there will be entry for egg,regardless if its 0 but the value is already there so use `update` query

Comment: Unless you have some guarantee that only a single process is ever making any changes to your tables (and a pool of agents _could_ be operating in parallel on your shopping list, right?), you will want to guard against the case where two processes are buying eggs at the same time (or almost the same time) by somehow making sure that "double buys" have the same effect as a "single buy". And you'll also want to make sure that either *both* tables are modified or *neither* is modified when eggs are bought - in case a process dies in the middle or one of the table updates fails for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write query like this

```
UPDATE alreadybought
SET quantity= (
    SELECT quantity FROM haveToBuy WHERE product="egg"
)
WHERE product="egg"
```

And you can fire another update query to set the value in `haveToBuy` table to set egg quantity to 0

To get sum of 2 values I can give you an example like below and you can modify it using your needs

```
select sum(quantity)+sum(newvalue) from message where product="egg"
```

or you can use it without `sum` as well

```
select quantity+newvalue from message where product="egg"
```

Be careful with using something like this query because you need to validate all the values before you submit it in the query and make sure the datatypes are same

Comment: Hey, that sound good, But how do I sum up both values? Like:
New Value = value + value of other table

Comment: @user3444297 look for `sum` function in mysql

Comment: Hello, I tried something like this, but it doesnt work yet:

UPDATE alreadybought SET eggs +(SELECT eggs FROM haveToBuy...) WHERE,,,

I guess there is something wrong with the sum

Comment: @user3444297 of course its wrong because what is the value of `egg`, After `SET` there should be column name not value name,for example in your case column name is `quantity` not `egg` so it should be `SET quantity = (SELECT quantity form haveToBuy)`

Comment: The updated code would look something like this, yet it still has mistakes I guess:

$query = mysql_query ("UPDATE alreadyBought SET quantity = (SELECT quantity FROM alreadyBought WHERE productname='$productname') + (SELECT quantity FROM haveToBuy WHERE ID='$ID')   ");

Comment: @user3444297 for `update` you need `where` condition as well just like i included in my answer.For example if you want to change value of `egg` as per your question here than your query should be like this `UPDATE alreadyBought SET quantity = (SELECT quantity FROM alreadyBought WHERE productname='$productname') + (SELECT quantity FROM haveToBuy WHERE ID='$ID') where product="egg"`